# what is servable mean in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I'm newest to tensorflow serving. Still confused with `servable` after read official tutorial. It seems like a `servable` is a `tensorflow session`, but has versions. It also looks like a model, but a `servable` may also correspond to a fraction of a model.
So what is `servable` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer it in a simple way.

A Servable, as per my understanding, is nothing but a Directory generated by Saving the Model, either using `SavedModelBuilder` or using `export_saved_model`. The contents of a Servable are shown below.

```
assets/
assets.extra/
variables/
    variables.data-?????-of-?????
    variables.index
saved_model.pb
```

If we use `SavedModelBuilder` to Save a Model, we need to explicitly mention the Version Numbers. Suppose if the Name of the Model is `export`, then we should mention the Export Directory as `/usr/local/google/home/mothukuru/Jupyter_Notebooks/export/1` or 
`/usr/local/google/home/mothukuru/Jupyter_Notebooks/export/2`, etc..

That is, we need to explicitly mention the version numbers.

If we use `export_saved_model`, versioning will be taken care automatically, mostly, based on time stamps. Example,

```
/usr/local/google/home/mothukuru/Jupyter_Notebooks/export/1554294699
/usr/local/google/home/mothukuru/Jupyter_Notebooks/export/1554736143
```

So, to answer your questions:

Q1. It seems like a servable is a tensorflow session, but has versions.

A1. Yes, it is a Session which has Versions. In that Session, we run the Model and we Save it

Q2.  It also looks like a model

A2. Yes, it is a Model, which is Saved using `SavedModelBuilder` or using `export_saved_model`.

Q3. But a servable may also correspond to a fraction of a model.

A3. Yes. This Answer has 2 parts.

i. `saved_model.pb` comprises of Training Graph and Inference Graph. Inference Graph is the Key to TF Serving.

ii. There are 2 folders named `assets`. The folder `assets`  contains auxiliary files such as vocabularies, etc. That also will be useful during Serving.

Comment: Thank you @RakTheGeek. I'm clear now. Versions are used to make a `servable stream`.